# How to keep thread alive without blocking app?

Tags: android, multithreading

In order to execute some IO operations in my app I wrote a thread, there's nothing on its run method but it has several other methods, like void write(String filename, String data) and void create(String filename), all of which work like a charm. My question is, I used to think this thread was running on the background or something like this but since after removing the .run() statement on my main activity calling said methods still works, how can I have a thread running and waiting for a message from the activity without blocking the app? And second question, since the methods are still working does it mean they are being executed on the main UI thread when I call them from my main activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the methods to run on the said thread you will have to have to call your methods from the thread and not from any other thread.

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Then use `WorkerThread.mHandler.postRunnable` or `sendMesssage` for the work to be done on another thread.

Comment: what do you mean by bidirectional?

Comment: Can I send messages back to the main activity through the Thread's Handler or do I need to provide said activity with its own Handler?

Comment: You will have to create a handler in main thread, to send messages back to main thread

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`start()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method, instead of the `run()`.

With `run()` you are running the given `Runnable` in the calling thread.

With `start()` you are starting a new thread that handles this `Runnable`

Comment: Your answer helped as well so I'll give you +1 though I can't accept both.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a que for processing stuff when delivered, you need to make use of android's native stuff which is the best option available:

- HandlerThread
- Looper
- Handler
- Message

For examples, read [this](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/42) and [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/convenient-messaging-between-threads).